# Data loss under Linux

Tags: directory, debian, loss, fsck

I work under linux debian buster.
This morning I worked as usual and my PC crashed. I forced it to shut down and when I restarted, it presents the terminal with initramfs (if I'm not mistaken) by inviting me to do an fsck.
This is not the first time this has happened to me. I usually do an fsck -y / dev / sda1 then fsck -y / dev / sda3 for my root and home partition.
But this morning, after crashing, when I did that, he scrolled through several messages quickly, and that worried me. At the end I restarted my PC and voila, I can no longer find my work folder. In fact, I have a folder containing two other folders. Hey there is only one visible folder left. All of my shortcuts to the missing folder no longer works.
When I make a df -h, the size appears as if the file is present, but impossible to see it. It is not in / lost + found
I have a global search in my home, and nothing
I can no longer work, all my work was there, I have a 1 month old backup, but good.
If really really, you have a solution, please I'm desperate.
My disk is partitioned into 4 including 3 for linux and one for ntfs
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

too happy
I found my data.
What made me have 0.5% of hope (I must admit I was at the edge of the window with the pc and looking for my data one last time), was the size of my partition. When I right click on home and I look at the size I have 31go, and with a
df -h
and as a result:
/ dev / sda3 192G 95G 87G 53% / home

or 95 GB of used, compared to 31 GB above, so where are the 60 GB?
Before the problem, I was around 95 GB in size.

It is true that several messages including the word inode or node (I do not remember) with numbers quickly appeared during fsck -y

Someone suggested I take a look at / home / lost + found, and when I did, I saw nothing. But when I logged in as root in a terminal, then "cd / home" and ls lost + found ", I saw numbers like # 13032 # 13036 # 1181667, and a folder with the number # 4703. So I made a "chmod 777 -R lost + found" in order to be able to access it via my account (simple user account). Once the command was executed and after a few minutes, I opened / home / lost + found via a "nemo" file explorer and TADAM, all my data was there.
I’ve done SEVERAL SAVINGS and vowed not to trust fsck -y anymore, even though it’s a great tool, but I’ll use it with caution.